# Issues with combining several forest plots into one figure - R

Tags: r, r-forestplot, meta-analysis

I've conducted a meta-analysis and generated forest plots in R. I'm now wanting to combine two forest plots into one figure. I've looked at other similar questions (see [Combine several forestplot object in one graph in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266791/combine-several-forestplot-object-in-one-graph-in-r) and [Plotting two graphs getting the error: Cannot convert object of class list into a grob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481703/plotting-two-graphs-getting-the-error-cannot-convert-object-of-class-list-into)) but haven't had any luck.

I keep getting errors about the type of plot I'm trying to combine (e.g., not liking the list format or it not being a grob).

First, I created my forest plots - I've had no issues.

```
comparison1=metabin(event.e = hl_p, n.e = hl_t, event.c = th_p, 
                         n.c = th_t, data = dd_RR1, sm = "RR", method = "Inverse", 
                         studlab = dd_RR1$study_name, method.tau = "REML")

comparison2=metabin(event.e = hl_p, n.e = hl_t, event.c = th_p, 
                         n.c = th_t, data = dd_RR2, sm = "RR", method = "Inverse", 
                         studlab = dd_RR2$study_name, method.tau = "REML")

dd_1 <- forest(comparison1, layout = "JAMA", common = FALSE, random = TRUE, overall = TRUE, rightcols = "w.random", 
       leftcols = c("studlab", "event.e", "n.e", "event.c","n.c", "effect", "ci"),
       leftlabs = c("Passed", "", "Passed", "", "RR (95% CI)"), label.e = "HL", 
       label.c = "TH", fs.heading = 12, ff.random = "bold", showweights=TRUE)

dd_2 <- forest(comparison2, layout = "JAMA", common = FALSE, random = TRUE, overall = TRUE, rightcols = "w.random", 
       leftcols = c("studlab", "event.e", "n.e", "event.c","n.c", "effect", "ci"),
       leftlabs = c("Passed", "", "Passed", "", "RR (95% CI)"), label.e = "HL", 
       label.c = "TH", fs.heading = 12, ff.random = "bold", showweights=TRUE)

fp1 <- forest(metainf(comparison1, pooled = "random"))
fp2 <- forest(metainf(comparison2, pooled = "random"))
```

This is the code I've used to try and combine fp1 and fp2 - figured I'd try with just two at the start. This just generated a blank-white plot.

```
library(ggplotify)
library(patchwork)

fp1 <- grid2grob(print(fp1))
fp2 <- grid2grob(print(fp2))
fp_both <- wrap_elements(fp1) / wrap_elements(fp2)
fp_both
```

Among other ways, this is another option I've tried.

```
my_plot_list2 <- list(fp1, fp2)
ggarrange(plotlist = my_plot_list2, labels = c('A', 'B'), nrow = 2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try using `gforce/forestplot` instead, it appears that package has some build in gridi capacity

Comment: Did you try it with the [gridExtra](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) package?